# IPv4 Address Sharing Issue? Trying to map IPv4 address from host OS to BT5 VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ip-address, nat, nmap

I'm having a general networking issue in regards to my Backtrack 5 (x64) KDE VM in VirtualBox. The VM appears to be on a separate subnet, but for my purposes, I'd like to include the VM in the private class C network (192.168.x.x).

Do you know why the VM is using a Class B private address as opposed to a Class C? My understanding with NAT is that the system would use a single IPv4 address to connect the virtual machine to the network.

How can I change the VM config. so that I can access the 192.168.x.x subnet?

---

Technical details of VM/network config.

- Using NAT adapter from Virtualbox to communicate w/LAN
- Nmap scan of 10.0.2.1-254 returns 5 active hosts on LAN

I'm trying to:

- Use nmap to perform a scan of the 192.168.2.x subnet

The issue:

- Can only scan LAN if querying 10.0.2.1-254, shouldn't I be querying 192.168.2.1-254? 
  Command used:
  **nmap -sP 10.0.2.1-254**

---

Windows 7 x64 (Host)

```
Windows IP Configuration
...
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : EC-55-F9-C8-67-38
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f9cc:d2f8:a30d:15b0%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.4(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
```

Backtrack 5 VirtualBox VM (Guest)

```
root@bt:~# ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:40:ed:f7
          inet addr:10.0.2.15 Bcast:10.0.2.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe40:edf7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
          ...
```

Comment: Back track questions are off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of NAT, use bridge adapter. If your Host (Win) is getting IP through DHCP then your vm (bt) will also get IP through the same source.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Upon switching NAT to bridge adapter, will I be able to use both the Host, and Guest OSs without network issues? 
The BT5 environment isn't permanent by any means, just something that I can open up on the fly, and work on simultaneously.

Comment: You should be good using bridge for working on both Host and Guest simultaneously.